# Busca em php com UNION - erro mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, algoritmo-de-busca

estou fazendo um simples sistema de busca que traga somente as quantidades de resultados das tabelas especificadas O problema é que está ocasionando um erro devido as tabelas serem diferentes e suas linhas. Vejam meu script.

```
$q = $_GET['busca'];

$query= '
        SELECT * FROM noticia WHERE noticia_title LIKE "%'.$q.'% or noticia_content LIKE "%'.$q.'%"
    UNION
        SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE evento_nome LIKE "%'.$q.'% or evento_content LIKE "%'.$q.'%"
        UNION 
    SELECT * FROM albuns WHERE album_name LIKE "%'.$q.'%" or album_descricao LIKE "%'.$q.'%"  
    ';

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($count == 0) {
        echo "Nenhum resultado!";
} else {
    if ($count == 1) {
        echo "1 resultado encontrado!";
}
        if ($count > 1) {
        echo "$count resultados encontrados!";
    }
        while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "";
    }
    }
```

O erro que está sendo ocasionado é:
**Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in**

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você está esquecendo de fechar aspas em dois pontos... 1) SELECT * FROM noticia WHERE noticia_title LIKE "%'.$q.'%"   2) SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE evento_nome LIKE "%'.$q.'%"

Comment: @FernandoSouza Fiz a correção, não havia nem percebido. Mais o error persiste. Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: tenta fazer assim: mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); e vê o que aparece

Comment: Deu o seguinte erro: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: As tabelas [noticia , eventos e albuns] tem a quantidade de colunas diferentes.. se você puder editar sua pergunta e colocar a estrutura dessas tabelas, ajudará bastante.

Comment: Olá, coloquei, veja !

Comment: Então... o erro que você está tendo é por que você não consegue fazer um select * from nessas tabelas usando union por que a quantidade de colunas é diferente..

Comment: O que posso fazer para resolver essa seleção e resultados. Tem como ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme conversado nos comentários:

1) Faltavam aspas duplas nos dois primeiros selects

```
SELECT * FROM noticia WHERE noticia_title LIKE "%'.$q.'%" 
SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE evento_nome LIKE "%'.$q.'%"
```

2) Após adicionar `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` foi identificado o seguinte erro:

> The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

3) Para resolver este problema você deve fazer um `SELECT` com a mesma quantidade de colunas. Exemplo:

```
$query= '
        SELECT noticia_id FROM noticia WHERE noticia_title LIKE "%'.$q.'%" or noticia_content LIKE "%'.$q.'%"
    UNION
        SELECT evento_id FROM eventos WHERE evento_nome LIKE "%'.$q.'%" or evento_content LIKE "%'.$q.'%"
    UNION 
        SELECT album_id FROM albuns WHERE album_name LIKE "%'.$q.'%" or album_descricao LIKE "%'.$q.'%"  
    ';
```

Comment: Olá companheiro! Deu certo agora! Show de bola! Poderia me explicar porque foi necessário colocar a primeira coluna da tabela em cada SELECT?

Comment: Quando você utiliza o operador UNION em um SELECT você tem que se atentar a alguns detalhes como: 1) A quantidade de colunas devem ser iguais.. 2) O Tipo dos dados devem ser similares... 3) As colunas devem estar na mesma ordem...    Veja este [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) onde fala um pouco mais sobre isto.  Ah! e se possível aceite a minha resposta como a correta.

Comment: Ah entendi! Muito obrigado pelo apoio!